# Custom TCPListener closing TCPClient before reply

Tags: android, xamarin, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am using the following TCPListener in Xamarin.Android that has served me well in the past, but only have one problem with it...
In the following piece of code within `startListener()` (Full code below)

```
while (!NS.DataAvailable && sta)
{
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
 if (cntr > 20)
 {
  TCPC.Close();
  NS = null;
  break;
 }
 cntr++;
}
```

The TCPClient gets closed if the NetworkSteam has not data to Send(Reply) or Receive for a period of time, which is not a problem and do need it to close this.
Problem is that I can set this "timeout" between changing `Thread.Sleep(50)` value and `cntr > 20` value, but becomes very difficult to predict how long this timeout needs to be depending on what data was received, as I need to perform long running operations on the data before sending the reply (long running as in could be 3sec or 30sec), if I set it too short then it closes my TCP client before I am able to reply, if I set it too long the port is blocked for many seconds after sending the reply and I cannot send the next command until this timeout has expired. Is there a better way to handle this timeout, or a better implementation not using TCPListener

```
    private static void startListener()
    {
        ListenStarted = true;
        TCPL = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8012);
        try
        {
            TCPL.Start();
            sta = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log Error
        }

        while (sta)
        {
            try
            {
                TCPC = TCPL.AcceptTcpClient();
                TCPC.NoDelay = true;

                NS = TCPC.GetStream();
                while (NS.CanRead && NS.CanWrite && sta)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    int cntr = 0;
                    while (!NS.DataAvailable && sta)
                    {

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                        if (cntr > 20)
                        {
                            TCPC.Close();
                            NS = null;
                            break;
                        }
                        cntr++;

                    }
                    if (NS == null)
                        break;
                    while (NS.DataAvailable && sta)
                    {
                        int bte = NS.ReadByte();
                        if (bte == -1)
                            break;

                        if ((char)bte != (char)0x03)
                        {
                            sb.Append((char)bte);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            processDataSets(sb);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                sta = false;
            }
        }

        ListenStarted = false;
        NS = null;
    }
```

Comment: Does your server just send some data on connection? Could you visualize the data flow you want to achieve? It's hard to understand, because the code is pretty "complicated".

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe The roles in this case is kind of reversed, in that the Mobile Android device is the "Server" in that it hosts the Listener, and a Windows Service send messages to the Mobile device containing person information in a Datatable that has been serialised, this is then Saved on the Mobile and some business logic applied before replying to the Windows Service.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Further explanation of the code above: The while(sta) loop ALWAYS runs, the while (NS.CanRead && NS.CanWrite) loop runs as soon as it gets data, the while (NS.DataAvailable) loop then runs inserting all the data received into StringBuilder (sb) passing the data to processDataSets where it is processed, meanwhile the while (!NS.DataAvailable) loop started running as all data was received, and is  waiting for more data that may be in-coming OR out-going, and therein lays the problem - I don't know when the data is finished processing and has replied, so I can close TCPClient